# "conda install" shows Solving Environment: failed, PackagesNoutFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, anaconda, conda

I'm stucked with conda in Mac OS.

Conda command, like "conda install", "conda update" doesn't work. When I run these kind of command, it shows "**Solving environment: failed**", "**PackagesNotFoundError**". I pasted the example below.

I tried to reinstall anaconda, but I couldn't even run "conda install anaconda-clean". It shows the same kind of result as below.

```
$conda update conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> cryptography==1.7.1=py36_0
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> dill==0.2.5=py36_0
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> idna==2.2=py36_0
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> matplotlib==2.0.0=np111py36_0
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> numexpr==2.6.1=np111py36_2
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> numpy==1.11.3=py36_0
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> pycosat==0.6.1=py36_1
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> pycurl==7.43.0=py36_2
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> readline==6.2=2
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> scipy==0.18.1=np111py36_1
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> setuptools==27.2.0=py36_0
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> tk==8.5.18=0
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::anaconda==4.3.0=np111py36_0 -> xz==5.2.2=1

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I'm thinking it may happened because I was using "pip" to install some packages, not "conda".

Please tell me if you need additional information. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Probably related https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9004

Comment: Thank you. It also helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem and finally resolved it by using this guide  to uninstall conda and anaconda manually (though i was unable to make head or tails of step 4 in the link, which involved removing package service files in the Library folder) :

https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-anaconda-on-a-mac

1.Quit the Anaconda app and Force quit any Anaconda processes running in the background using the Activity Monitor.

3.Remove the Anaconda app from the Applications folder.

4.Remove the following using rm -rf in terminal:

~/anaconda3
~/.bash_profile-anaconda3.bak
~/.condarc
~/.conda
~/.anaconda

I then reinstalled anaconda and everything seems to work now.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and 
provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.